# Dynamic date Caluculation in Java script

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I Am having two dataPickers of `dijit/form/DateTextBox`. One for startdate and another one for Enddate.

I want to check whether  "`Enddate > startdate+ 90days` 3month)", if yes then I need to reset the end-date with startdate+ 90days.

format which am getting from DateTextBox `2018-04-25`. Please help on this

```
var fromDate=digit.byId('startDate');

if(fromDate!=null) {

  var fromtimestamp=new Date(digit.byId('startDate')).getTime();
  var endtimestamp=new Date(digit.byId('endDate')).getTime();
  var timestamp= new Date(digit.byId('startDate')).getTime+ (30 *24*60*60*1000);

  if(endtimestamp>timestamp) {
    // wants to reset with startdate+ 90days
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you link a snippet of the code you have so far?

Comment: hi slee423 added the same

Comment: It appears that you're referencing you're `timestamp` parameter incorrectly. You have it set as `timestamp= new Date(digit.byId('startDate')).getTime+ (30 *24*60*60*1000);` whereas it should be set to `timestamp= new Date(digit.byId('startDate')).getTime() + 30 *24*60*60*1000;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this but using [dateBox](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html#changing-constraints-on-the-fly) min constaraint setting a change event in your start date , then set the `digit.byId('endDate').constraints.min` start date + 90
as :

```
digit.byId('startDate').on("change",function() {
  var end = new Date(this.value);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + 90);
  digit.byId('endDate').constraints.min = end;
})
```

See below programmatic snippet :

```js
require(["dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dijit/form/Button","dojo/on" ,
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(DateTextBox,Button, On ) {

  var startdate = new DateTextBox({
      constraints:{
        datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd'
      }
    }, "startDate");
    
    var enddate = new DateTextBox({
      constraints:{
        datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd'
      }
    }, "endDate");
    
    startdate.on("change",function() {
      var end = new Date(this.value);
      end.setDate(end.getDate() + 90);
      enddate.constraints.max = end;
      enddate.constraints.min = new Date(this.value);
    })
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
  start :<div id="startDate" ></div>
  
  end : <div id="endDate" ></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Berrita, But I can select any date after start date for end date. but here its not allowing me to select any date till nighty days.

Comment: @jcrshankar I did not understant , could you please explain , do you need to select only date within the 90 day ( between start date and 90 ?)

Comment: see my updated answer if I have understand your need

Comment: I can select any date prior to current date or future date as Start date. where as end date I can select any date after start date but not greater than 90 days from start date

Comment: Great I'm glad that helped you :)